# Microsoft Graph API Incremental Permisisons

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Can I do incremental Permissions with the msgraph-sdk-javascript library?  For example, a user signs in only with the profile but later authorizes access to to their email account or calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/dev/package.json), the Microsoft Graph JavaSciprt SDK doesn't include an authentication library. It is only a higher level wrapper for calls and serialization of objects.

It is your responsibility to obtain an access token and provide it to the library. You can pass in a token this way:

```js
var client = MicrosoftGraph.Client.init({
  authProvider: done => {
    //first parameter takes an error if you can't get an access token
    done(null, "PassInAccessTokenHere");
  }
});
```

Microsoft is going through an important transformation for the authentication and authorization endpoints (v1 vs v2). One of the major differences is that v2 supports scopes (as opposed to resources in v1) which provides support for [incremental consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare#incremental-and-dynamic-consent).

Microsoft currently maintains two authentication libraries:

- `Adal.js` which targets the v1 endpoint (and doesn't support incremental consent)
- `MSAL.js` which targets the v2 endpoint (and support incremental consent)

Lastly, v2 has a [set of limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-compare) in terms of supported flows as well as supported APIs.

**I recommend you read a lot on the subject before making a choice to make sure you won't end up in a dead end of "something is missing in that version" in the middle of the project.**

Comment: I was going through this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial  and it makes a call to the following API for authorization - https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?  Since it uses V2.0 of the auth library - it would provide incremental auth? i.e. user signs in with Microsoft account with just the access to their name and email address and then later upgrades it to to the email access?

Comment: That example leverages v2 endpoints but they are not leveraging any authentication library, implementing the the manually. It's a lot of manual work, but good to learn.

Comment: thanks.  I have found an example for the framework that I am using https://github.com/sunilbandla/vue-msal-sample  Appreciate all your help.